# Bluetooth Connectivity Challenges - Connecting Sphero BOLT with Ubuntu

Tags: bolt, sphero-api, sphero

I am interested in utilizing the Sphero Bolt robot for my research. My goal is to establish a connection between the Bolt and Ubuntu using Bluetooth, and program it using Python. Since the Bolt utilizes a specific BLE protocol for connectivity, it cannot be connected through regular Bluetooth channels, and I haven't been able to find the protocol online.

1. Has anyone successfully connected the Bolt with any operating system (Windows, Linux), excluding the EDU App?
2. What initial steps should I take to enable this connection?
3. Are there any Python libraries available to support programming the Bolt?

I've successfully established a Bluetooth connection with the Sphero Mini and employed the [Sphero_mini](https://github.com/MProx/Sphero_mini) library and the testing scripts work. But Bolt I do not know how to connect it.